# Three buttons powershell pop-up

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I'm trying to create a very simply powershell pop-up with three buttons.

The first two buttons execute a different function each and the third once allows the user to cancel and exit.

So it would look like this :

| Button1 | Button2 | Exit |

I'm a noob and all I can do is a yes/no question with this :

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
  $answer = $wshell.Popup("Blahblahblah",0,"My title",64+4)

if ($answer -eq 7){
```

Comment: You are limited to some buttons when using builtin Wscript popups or .NET messageboxes. https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-popup.html. If you want to display custom buttons, you need to create your own form. Look for this ref: Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF with visual studio 2019, and create a popup like you want. And next take the xml for your code.

Example of utilisation of WPF : https://akril.net/creer-une-interface-graphique-wpf-en-powershell/